# How unsafe is lightning?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, lightning

Given our extensive use of wireless/wired technology (mobile phones, chargers, etc.), how dangerous is it to use these amidst a thunderstorm? Is it dangerous enough to consider avoiding? Is there a distinction between wireless (i.e. mobile phone) and wired (i.e. charging laptop)?

Is lightning dangerous enough for us to resolutely stay indoors to avoid being struck?

Please back with scientific explanations. My search has not yielded many valid *recent* information on the subject, and someone I know is claiming it to be significantly dangerous.

Note: I'd like to have solid scientific information to argue my point back. I am a high school physics student, so not much of a physicist just yet.

Comment: What makes you think cell phone use increases the risk of injury from lightning?

Comment: "someone I know"  <-- that should be a red flag!  Guarantee you that whoever said that is at best a fool and at worst  a Qanon member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a false equivalency going on here about "electric stuff". It's all being thrown under the same bin due to lack of knowledge: lightning, radios, wires, everything. For example: Bears, animals, are dangerous, and since I don't know anything about bears or animals then I assume all animals are dangerous. That is what is happening here.

Electric fields apply forces to charges. More intense electric fields push charges harder and promote charges to jump (i.e. sparks, lightning strikes). Look up how electric fields become more intense with narrower shapes and sharper corners. Now try to figure out what about a cell phone, charger, or laptop satisfies that criteria.

[image]

https://www.a-levelphysicstutor.com/field-elect-2.php

[image]
https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/18-7-conductors-and-electric-fields-in-static-equilibrium/

Comment: thanks for guiding me! it makes sense now.